# MongoDB aggregate query to filter documents created 7 days ago

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to filter the dataset to extract documents which were created 7 days ago **OR** a Month ago **OR** Documents created at any date.

filter documents based on createdAt field in document.

**Dataset:-**

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ae"),
    "type": "A",
    "source": "B",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-04-17T07:55:00.368Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-04-17T07:55:00.368Z"),
    
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ad"),
    "type": "B",
    "source": "A",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-04-23T07:55:00.368Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-04-23T07:55:00.368Z"),
    
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ce"),
    "type": "A",
    "source": "C",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-04-17T07:55:00.368Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-04-17T07:55:00.368Z"),
    
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1cb"),
    "type": "A",
    "source": "B",
    "user": ObjectId("622b56250b0af6b049c387d6"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-04-24T07:55:00.368Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-04-24T07:55:00.368Z"),
    
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1cb"),
    "type": "A",
    "source": "B",
    "user": ObjectId("622b56250b0af6b049c387d6"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-03-24T07:55:00.368Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-03-24T07:55:00.368Z"),
    
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ce"),
    "type": "A",
    "source": "C",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-03-17T07:55:00.368Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-03-17T07:55:00.368Z"),
    
  },
  
]
```

**MongoDB aggregate query:-**

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      paramType: "All",
      paramSource: "All",
      paramCreatedAt:"All",
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          user: ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              paramType: {
                $eq: "All"
              }
            },
            {
              $expr: {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramType",
                  "$type"
                ],
                
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              paramSource: {
                $eq: "All"
              }
            },
            {
              $expr: {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramSource",
                  "$source"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      output: {
        totalCount: {
          $count: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 6
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "paramSource": false,
      "paramType": false,
      
    }
  }
])
```

how to filter to get documents created in the last 7 days or 30 days or any date.

paramCreatedAt will take one of the following values `[All dates, 7 days ago, a month ago]`

**Example:-**

- If the `All dates` filter is applied then display all records.
- If `7 days` filter is applied display records created from the current date (which can be any day not necessary that it should be sunday) to 7 days back.
- If `30 days` filter applied then display records created in last 30 days

Comment: Documents created at "any date" means ... all documents, subject to extra `$match` on `user` or other fields, yes?   And:  do you mean 7 days ago EXACTLY or 7 or more days ago?    Same question for a month ago.   For example, I could have many docs created between 1-Mar-2022 and 1-Apr-2022 because March is "a month ago" from now (April).   But another view is ONLY docs created 24-Mar-2022, which is 31 days before today (24-Apr-2022).

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I actually want to filter documents created in the current week from the current date to 7 days back.

Comment: Clarity:  Current week means exactly what?  Sun-Sat?   Mon-Sun?   *current week* from the *current date to 7 days back* has contradictions.   Don't answer here; edit the question and provide examples of how those date boundaries need to be treated.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti not necessarily sun-sat it can be between any day of the week and 7 days back. please check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your skeleton is pretty neat and you are actually quite close. For the date filtering, just use `$dateDiff` to return the date difference in days and compare it with the days interval your selected(i.e. 7 days or 30 days) by using `$switch`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      paramType: "All",
      paramSource: "All",
      paramCreatedAt: "All dates"// [All dates, 7 days ago, a month ago]
      
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          user: ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              paramType: {
                $eq: "All"
              }
            },
            {
              $expr: {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramType",
                  "$type"
                ],
                
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              paramSource: {
                $eq: "All"
              }
            },
            {
              $expr: {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramSource",
                  "$source"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              paramCreatedAt: {
                $eq: "All dates"
              }
            },
            {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    "$in": [
                      "$paramCreatedAt",
                      [
                        "7 days ago",
                        "a month ago"
                      ]
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lte: [
                      {
                        "$dateDiff": {
                          "startDate": "$createdAt",
                          "endDate": "$$NOW",
                          "unit": "day"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "$switch": {
                          "branches": [
                            {
                              "case": {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$paramCreatedAt",
                                  "7 days ago"
                                ]
                              },
                              "then": 7
                            },
                            {
                              "case": {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$paramCreatedAt",
                                  "a month ago"
                                ]
                              },
                              "then": 30
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      output: {
        totalCount: {
          $count: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 6
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "paramSource": false,
      "paramType": false,
      
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hLT680qQvNW) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach using `$facet`.   `$facet` is very handy because it allows you to "match and group in parallel" and create *overlapping* buckets of documents.  A single pipeline with `$group` and `$cond` on the aggregation field works well for "if/then/elif/elif/else" constructions where overlaps are not desired and an order of precedence is desired.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // Initial filter(s):                                                                                                    
    {$match: {user: ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")}},

    // Create a single version of "now" from the perspective of the                                                          
    // CLIENT to use in queries to follow.                                                                                   
    // To create such a target date from the perspective of the SERVER,                                                      
    // use  {$addFields: {DD: '$$NOW'}}                                                                                      
    // Probably overkill but OK.                                                                                             
    {$addFields: {DD: new ISODate()}},

    {$facet: {
        "all": [ ],   // not exciting!  :-)                                                                                  

        "exactly_7_days_ago": [
            {$match: {$expr:
                      {$eq: [7, {$floor: {$divide:[{$subtract:['$DD', '$createdAt'] }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24]}} ]}
                     }}
        ],
        "everything_from_last_month": [
            {$match: {$expr:
                      {$eq: [1, {$subtract:[{$month: '$DD'}, {$month: '$createdAt'} ]} ]}
                     }}
        ],
        "only_one_day_from_last_month": [
            {$match: {$expr:
                      {$and: [
                          {$eq: [1, {$subtract:[{$month: '$DD'}, {$month: '$createdAt'}]} ]},
                          {$eq: [0, {$subtract:[{$dayOfMonth: '$DD'}, {$dayOfMonth: '$createdAt'} ]} ]}
                      ]}
                     }}
        ],
    }}

]);
```